# What does here "backyard trail warrior" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, phrase-meaning

Here is the whole paragraph:

> Through the years, I’ve trended off into the mountain riding scene and
> that’s where my heart lies. Today though, I’m going to share with you
> some tips that might help you decide what is the best snowmobile for
> you. It doesn’t matter if you’re brand new to the sport, an ice
> fishing enthusiast, a backyard trail warrior or getting serious about
> loading up and heading high up into the alpine, I can guarantee you
> one thing… There is a snowmobile out there for you!

I am not a native English speaker and, to be honest, I did not really get the idea of this play on words. As an option, the author probably wanted to say that it is a person who conquers roads. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means someone who goes on snowmobiles as a hobby, and uses local trails.

"Backyard" literally means the garden behind the house. But metaphorically it can mean "ones local area".  Thus "backyard trails" are "local paths"

A warrior is literally a soldier but here it means someone who is brave, or ironically someone who does something for fun. There is an expression "weekend warrior" which means someone who goes and does sports on the weekend, but spends the week doing normal work.

So a "Backyard trail warrior" is someone who uses their snowmobile on local routes and for fun, not as their job or as a means to do something else (like ice fishing)  As I said, it is rather ironic. Suggesting that the person is only brave on local (and therefore safe) routes.